# all possible combination for NSum

Tags: java, algorithm

There is an array of `N` elements, and would like to sum `K` elements to get closest `sum` to `target` value.

for 3Sum, have solution for this

```
public int threeSumClosest(int[] nums, int target) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int result = 0;
 
    Arrays.sort(nums);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        int k = nums.length - 1;
        while (j < k) {
            int sum = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k];
            int diff = Math.abs(sum - target);
 
            if(diff == 0) return sum;
 
            if (diff < min) {
                min = diff;
                result = sum;
            }
            if (sum <= target) {
                j++;
            } else {
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

But Is there any way I could use generic solution for NSum, so that I could try summing of all possible combination of elements on the basis of `number of elements required to be sum to get closest value to target` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make 2D array of size  `A[K+1][Sum+1]`

Make a loop for `N` values.

For value `V` traverse array `A`.
If `A[k][s]>0` and `A[k+1][s+V]==0` for `k<K`, put V into the second cell.
This denotes that sum `s+V` might be composed from `k+1` elements with `V` as the last one.

After all check `A[K][sum]` and closest cells in K-th row